# railstutorial.org sample app login passwords not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have completed the sample app tutorial through section 10.4.1.  All my tests are green.  Prior to completing 10.4.1 everything was working as expected.  However, upon editing the _user.html.erb partial to add the delete link, the login function does not work.  No passwords for existing users are recognized.  If I create a new user the signup process works.  I can then logout and login with that new user's email and password, but the previously created accounts are inaccessible.  Not sure what to do about this.

_user.html.erb:

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to 'delete', user, method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: 'You sure?' } %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user= User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  # Confirms a logged-in user
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

end
```

No error messages from the rails server console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was even stupider than that.  I had edited the password of the first user as part of an exercise, but then the database got reset at a later point.  Had to use the initial default password, not the one I changed it to.  Feeling very sheepish at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Run your rails console in terminal with "rails c" command. Then type u = Users.all 
See, how many existing users in your database. Maybe that user, who you are talking about doesn't exist. Maybe it was a temporary session when you create that user.